# SHGetFolderPathW not working with japanese username

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode

Im trying to create one file in %APPDATA% using SHGetFolderPathW function. This function I guess is getting chars in unicode. I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 little project. The following code work in english version of win 8 but not in japanese version (username is japanese):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <tchar.h>    
#include <string>



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring output = L""; 

    WCHAR* folder = new WCHAR[2048]; 

    SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA,
        NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, folder
        );

    std::wstring str1 = folder;
    str1 += L"\\hola.txt";
    std::wcout << str1 << std::endl;

    std::string str(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // Create file in folder
    FILE * file;
    char *path = new char[str.length()+1];
    strcpy(path, str.c_str());
    file = fopen (path, "w");
    fputs ("Hello World",file);
    fclose (file);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The code is showing good path in English version, but in japanese, this path isn't right. I wonder if I have any way to use SHGetFolderPath in all languages. I'm googling two days but not solution found.

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible, but one may precise what "path isn't right" mean, to help others who can help you =)

Comment: @Hotted24 I mean the path not contains %APPDATA% path, once cout that.

Comment: `std::string str(str1.begin(), str1.end());` does NOT convert Unicode to anything.  Don't convert the wide string(s).

Comment: @RichardCritten And even if it did convert, the conversion would destroy the Japanese characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a wide string file path, use wide string version of `fopen`.  This should work:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR folder[MAX_PATH]; 

    SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA,
        NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, folder
        );

    std::wstring str1 = folder;
    str1 += L"\\hola.txt";

    // Create file in folder
    FILE * file;
    file = _wfopen (str1.c_str(), L"w");
    fputs ("Hello World",file);
    fclose (file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `delete[] folder` to avoid a memory leak. Otherwise use `WCHAR folder[2048]` or `std::vector<WCHAR> folder(2048)` instead.

Comment: Yeah, just copied his example.  It should be `MAX_PATH` as well...fixed.