# SHGetFolderPathW sometimes produces error -2147024773: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, ctypes

This may be related to [SHGetFolderPathW not working with japanese username](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28770296/5533635), but I suspect the use of Python `ctypes` is adding another wrinkle.

My code:

```
import ctypes

# Folder ID values for get_folder_path()
CSIDL_APPDATA       = 26
CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = 28

def get_folder_path(id):
    dll = ctypes.oledll.shell32
    buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(300)
    dll.SHGetFolderPathW(None, id, None, 0, buf)
    return buf.value
```

With Python 2.7.14, this works when run by a user with an ASCII username.

It *sometimes* works when run by a user with a non-ASCII username.

Specifically, we use PyInstaller to create a helper Windows executable bundled with our product. The product is installed with an NSIS installer. The NSIS installer runs that PyInstaller executable, which calls the function above, which produces a valid unicode pathname into which we store its log file.

Our product itself is a different executable, which also runs the same helper PyInstaller executable as a child process with different command-line arguments. The helper executable calls the same function (above) to determine where to put its log file. But for a user with a non-ASCII username, the `SHGetFolderPathW()` call produces the error I pasted initially.

For what it's worth, `os.environ['APPDATA']` contains `C:\Users\??????\AppData\Roaming`, which is why we call `SHGetFolderPathW()` at all.

This doesn't depend on our installer or our product. You can observe the same failure running python interactively under `cmd.exe` in an emacs shell buffer, whereas running python interactively in an ordinary Command Prompt window produces a valid unicode path.

I would have thought that Python 3.6.4, which generally handles Unicode strings better, would give better results. To my distress, it doesn't even work as well as Python 2.7.14 in this case: even in a top-level Command Prompt window, the `value` of the unicode buffer written by `SHGetFolderPathW()` is `C:\Users\??????\AppData\Roaming`. And `os.environ['APPDATA']` contains the same string.

And running interactively in an emacs shell buffer, it produces the same error as for Python 2.7.14.

I'm frankly baffled by this failure. If in fact it has already been asked and answered here, please point me to the solution. I wasn't able to find it.

Many thanks!

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Python?  Setting `.argtypes` for the function can help.  Pointers can get truncated on 64-bit if not explicitly declared.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, in the question title/summary: "error -2147024773: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I should have mentioned I've been using 32-bit Python for both Python 2 and Python 3. But the fact that the same function in the same executable sometimes succeeds suggests that it's not a pointer truncation problem, which I would expect to produce far more confused effects.

Comment: How is the error generated?  The code as posted works for me.

Comment: 1. Create a Windows user with a non-ASCII name. Log in as that user.

Comment: 2. I used gnu.org "NT" emacs 23.3. Not sure what other parent processes will produce the same error, but our product executable is one of them.
3. Get an emacs shell buffer. Running cmd.exe works.
4. Run an interactive python session within that shell buffer. I used 'python -i'.
5. Hand-type:

    import ctypes
    buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(300)
    ctypes.oledll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(None, 26, None, 0, buf)

That's when I get the error. If you get 0 instead, ask for buf.value.

Comment: bleah, you have to infer line breaks before bullet numbers and between 'import ctypes', 'buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(300)' and the 'ctypes.oledll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW()' call.

Comment: Please edit the question with more detail.  Comments don't display code well.  Have you tried setting .argtypes correctly?  With APPDATA being incorrect, it seems like an OS bug...btw, what specific OS version?  If you want to eliminate ctypes, write code to call the function in C or C++.

Comment: Ha, just noticed your linked question was an old answer of mine, using C.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce on Windows 10 64-bit, with Python 3.7 64-bit, and Python 2.7 32-bit.  Caveat, I used Chinese since I had a Chinese IME installed, but expect Japanese would be a similar result.  This result is in the standard cmd.exe window:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> dll=ctypes.oledll.shell32
>>> b=ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(300)
>>> dll.SHGetFolderPathW(None,28,None,0,b)
0
>>> b.value
'C:\\Users\\马克\\AppData\\Local'
```

---

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> dll=ctypes.oledll.shell32
>>> b=ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(300)
>>> dll.SHGetFolderPathW(None,28,None,0,b)
0
>>> b.value # those are the correct Unicode escape codes for 马克
u'C:\\Users\\\u9a6c\u514b\\AppData\\Local'
```

So I suspect the problem lies elsewhere, perhaps running in the emacs shell buffer?

Now in the Python 2 case, if you try to print those characters:

```
>>> s = u'C:\\Users\\\u9a6c\u514b\\AppData\\Local'
>>> print(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: character maps to <undefined>
>>> print s.encode('cp437','replace')
C:\Users\??\AppData\Local
```

If running in a different shell, it could be converting the Unicode to the shell's encoding, ignoring errors like in the example above.

Comment: Hmm, good to see your top-level Python 3.7 results. Not clear whether that's because I was using Python 3.6 or because it's on Windows 7. However -- this code always works for me when run in a top-level Command Prompt window, as you were doing. It consistently fails when the Python interpreter is run as a child process by our C++ product executable, and when there are non-ASCII characters in the Windows user name. I cited emacs to demonstrate that the failure is not specific to our product: you can reproduce it without engaging any of our compiled code.

Comment: When I say "fails," I mean that engaging `ctypes.oledll` causes `ctypes` to raise `WindowsError` when the `SHGetFolderPathW()` function returns nonzero `HRESULT`. We get those exceptions.

Comment: @Nat How are you getting the results of the child process?  If you are getting c:\users\???? that means the Unicode strings returned are getting converted to MBCS (local-specific multibyte encoding).

Comment: We log to a file encoded as UTF-8, and read it with a UTF-8 aware editor. Other lines in the same log file can display the correct non-ASCII username, for instance when the program is run at top level.